# Pandas drop duplicates based on one group and keep the last value

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"],
                     "col2": [0,0,0,1,1, 1],
                     "col3": [1,2,3,4,5, 6]})
```

**data**

```
  col1  col2    col3
0   a   0   1
1   a   0   2
2   a   0   3
3   a   1   4
4   a   1   5
5   a   1   6
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicates based on `col2 == 1` and keep the last entry

Using the below code I was able to keep the first and drop others.

```
data[~(data.duplicated(["col2"]) & data.col2.eq(1))]
```

```
col1    col2    col3
0   a   0   1
1   a   0   2
2   a   0   3
3   a   1   4
```

How to remove duplicates based on one category in a column and keep the last entry?

**Desired Output**

```
  col1  col2    col3
0   a   0   1
1   a   0   2
2   a   0   3
3   a   1   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) (or [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)):

```
# is the row not a 1 in col2?
m1 = data['col2'].ne(1)
# is the row the last of the group?
m2 = data.groupby('col2').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)
# or
# m2 = ~data['col2'].duplicated(keep='last')

# keep rows matching either condition
out = data[m1|m2]
```

Reversed logic:

```
# is the group a 1?
m1 = data['col2'].eq(1)
# is the row NOT the last one?
m2 = data['col2'].duplicated(keep='last')

# drop the rows matching both conditions
out = data[~(m1&m2)]
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     0     1
1    a     0     2
2    a     0     3
5    a     1     6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also concat the last row of the removed to the kept dataframe.

```py
m = df['col2'].eq(1)
out = pd.concat([df[~m], df[m].iloc[[-1]]]).sort_index()
```

```
print(out)

  col1  col2  col3
0    a     0     1
1    a     0     2
2    a     0     3
5    a     1     6
```